# Sudo does not log me in as root, but as "untitled 1"

Tags: linux, sudo

I was changing multiple configuration files and used `sudo -s` to make myself root for a little while.

However, after running `whoami` I was not `root`, but `untitled 1`.

```
joseph@MacBook-Air (ttys000) /Users/joseph$ whoami
joseph
joseph@MacBook-Air (ttys000) /Users/joseph$ sudo -s
bash-3.2# whoami
untitled 1  <----------- This
bash-3.2#
```

I don't know what's causing this but I *do* seem to have root access. For example, I can edit `/etc/hosts` with no problem.

There are some side effects to this though, for example logging in to an SSH server without specifying a username uses `untitled 1 @ server`.

Why is this happening and how can I diagnose it?

*macOS Sierra 10.12*

Comment: do you get the same thing with `sudo -i` ? I've always been told not to use `sudo -s` do to unclean issues regarding the environment presented to the subsequent commands. see here for some discussion on the root environment's corruption by sudo -s: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=983645&s=3a6799651a21ff286c0d855effea78e2&p=6188826#post6188826

Comment: @FrankThomas I apologise for the late reply. And no, using `sudo -i` then `whoami` shows the correct response of `root`.

Answer (score -3):

Within Ubuntu if you wish to enable the 'root' account then issue the command 'sudo passwd'.
When prompted enter your user password. You will then be asked to enter a new UNIX password; this will be the password for the root account so make sure you remember it! (note: as you type it in there is no indication not even '*'s, press enter and you will enter it again.) the root account is now active. To become root type 'su' and enter, you will be prompted for the root password , enter and now you will see the root prompt (#) instead of ($).

From Ubuntu 7.1 unleased Linux by Sams

Comment: So can you quote and **properly** cite your source? Of course a book on Ubuntu has what to do with OS X?

Comment: Ahh, I suppose I saw the comment quoting ubuntuforums. Listen, I am a newbie but I thought i'd try be helpful.

Comment: We appreciate the effort but edit your question and improve it